# jQuery - Do UI change after other UI change is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I execute `$("#login").toggle("drop", {direction: "left"});` then after THAT is completely finished... do `$("#register").toggle("drop", {direction: "right"});`. Because the `DIVS` are not floated and at the same time they stack up against each other when they `drop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) can take a second parameter that is a callback, put the second UI change in that callback.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#switch-to-login').live("click",function(){

        $("#login").toggle("drop", {direction: "left"}, function() {
           $("#register").toggle("drop", {direction: "right"});
        });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback:

```
$("#login").toggle("drop", {direction: "left"}, function(){
        $("#register").toggle("drop", {direction: "right"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FzsZS/

I'm on an iPad so I had to redo all the code etc. sorry about that.